# If a passphrase for a luks container is discovered, can that reveal another passphrase?

Tags: encryption, luks

I've been looking for an answer for this scenario -
say I've got a volume encrypted with a long passphrase. something like a skeleton key passphrase thats used for a number of volumes. This volume though isn't that important though and would like to allow another user to open it from time to time. Obviously I don't want the skeleton passphrase out there, so if I add a new passphrase for this user, can they decrypt the volume, recover the master key and then use this to recover my passphrase?

Will having access to the master key make recovery of my passphrase any easier at all?

It seems it doesn't, from what I've read, ie if you have a volume mapped and you've forgotten the password, people are generally recommended to recover the master key and then use that to add a new slot.. I would like to have it confirmed though.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct: Any key slot can decrypt the master key, but the master key cannot decrypt any key slot.